# Localização de um ponto dentro do intervalo de um arco

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, matemática, canvas

Procuro uma função em Javascript que retorne um valor aleatório dentro de um intervalo na área de um circulo. O intervalo iria ser ao longo do raio com distâncias equivalentes ao ponto central e o ponto final do raio, considerando também um intervalo de graus dentro deste circulo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dada a imagem. A área azul: distância do ponto central ao inicio do intervalo e distância da borda ao final do intervalo; área laranja: intervalo permitido à função aleatória.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há duas formas de fazer isso.

## 1. Chutando

A forma mais simplista é chutar coordenadas `(px, py)` e verificar se elas estão dentro da área desejada.

Para fazer essa verificação, faça assim:

1. Calcule a distância do ponto gerado em relação ao centro `(cx, cy)`:

   - `d = raiz((px - cx)² + (py - cy)²)`
2. Verifique se a distância `d` está dentro do menor e do maior raio permitido (`r1`, `r2`):

   - `r1 <  d < r2`
3. Para verificar se o ponto gerado está no quadrante desejado, verifique se as coordenadas são **maiores*** que as coordenadas do centro:

   - `px > cx`
   - `py > cy`

* No caso do eixo `y`, considerando que o plano cartesiano original, o correto seria `py` < `cy`. Porém, geralmente esse eixo é invertido nos sistemas gráficos que usamos nos computadores.

## 2. Calculando raio e ângulo

A segunda forma é um pouco mais complicada de início, mas resultará num ponto que se sabe estar dentro da área desejada.

1. Calcule um raio `r` aleatório entre o menor e do maior raio permitido (`r1`, `r2`):

   - `r = r1 + (r2 - r1) * rand`
2. Calcule um ângulo `a` dentro do quadrante desejado da circunferência:

   - `a = pi / 2 * rand` *
3. Calcule as coordenadas `(px, py)` resultantes:

   - `px = r * cosseno(a)`
   - `py = r * seno(a)`

* Fórmula usando o sistema de coordenadas invertido

## Colocando em prática o Cenário #2

O script abaixo implementa o método #2 apresentado acima. O cálculo da coordenada é basicamente o que o @bfavaretto implementou, porém com uma apresentação visual dos resultados.

```js
var data = {
    cx: 150,
    cy: 150,
    r: 100,
    r1: 40,
    r2: 70
};

function desenharAlvo(ctx) {
    //alvo completo
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#DDEEFF';
    ctx.arc(data.cx, data.cy, data.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); 
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    //coordenadas
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.moveTo(data.cx, data.cy - data.r); 
    ctx.lineTo(data.cx, data.cy + data.r); 
    ctx.moveTo(data.cx - data.r, data.cy); 
    ctx.lineTo(data.cx + data.r, data.cy); 
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    //raio menor
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#8899AA';
    ctx.arc(data.cx, data.cy, data.r1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); 
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    //raio maior
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#8899AA';
    ctx.arc(data.cx, data.cy, data.r2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); 
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function desenharDardo(ctx, x, y) {
    //alvo completo
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
    ctx.arc(data.cx + x, data.cy + y, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); 
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function aremessarDardo() {
    //passo 1
    var r = data.r1 + (data.r2 - data.r1) * Math.random();
    //passo 2
    var a = Math.PI / 2 * Math.random();
    //passo 3
    var x = r * Math.cos(a);
    var y = r * Math.sin(a);
    desenharDardo(ctx, x, y);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('alvo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
desenharAlvo(ctx);

setInterval(aremessarDardo, 250);
```

```html
<canvas id="alvo" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Belo exemplo :)

Comment: O Cenário do exemplo foi brilhante, com certeza, mas ainda falta uma questão...

As áreas não são exatamente dividias em quadrantes, podem variar, por exemplo, na imagem da questão o arco era dividido a quatro, mas e se fosse dividido, por exemplo, em 20? Como seria pra utilizar apenas um segmento desse circulo com a sua equação?

Comment: @GabrielMaia para variar em relação ao arco, você precisa ajustar apenas uma linha de código, a saber, a linha que calcula o ângulo `a`. No caso, eu gero um valor entre `0` e `PI/2`, que corresponde ao primeiro quadrante. Considerando que `2*PI` corresponde a toda a circunferência, você só precisa definir qual é o ângulo inicial e final, calculando então um valor aleatório entre esses dois valores.

Answer (score 3):

Com um possível erro de *off-by-one* nos meus números aleatórios, acho que é isto aqui:

```
// Ângulos mínimo e máximo no círculo, em radianos
var minDeg = Math.PI;
var maxDeg = Math.PI * 5/4;
// Ângulo sorteado
var ang = minDeg + ((maxDeg - minDeg) * Math.random());

// Valor do raio onde começa a área laranja
var minRaio = 10;
// Valor do raio onde termina a área laranja
var maxRaio = 20;
// Trecho sorteado do raio
var raio = minRaio + ((maxRaio - minRaio) * Math.random());

// Posição calculada
var x = raio * Math.cos(ang);
var y = raio * Math.sin(ang);
```

<sub>Nota: esta solução se baseia no sistema de coordenadas invertido e é uma implementação do segundo método explicado na resposta do @utluiz.</sub>